# Flask + Docker => No connection

Tags: python, docker, flask, flask-restful

I have a basic REST API implemented in Flask. I want to try using Docker to containerize it. I'm completely new to Docker, but based on what I was able to figure out on various forums, this is what I have set up.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR     /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY .env /app/.env
COPY . /app
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

requirements.txt

```
aiohttp==3.8.6
aiohttp-retry==2.8.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
blinker==1.6.3
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.1
click==8.1.7
distlib==0.3.7
filelock==3.12.4
Flask==2.3.0
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
flask-marshmallow==0.14.0
Flask-MySQL==1.5.2
Flask-MySQLdb==2.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
frozenlist==1.4.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.29.0
multidict==6.0.4
mysqlclient==2.2.0
packaging==23.2
platformdirs==3.11.0
PyJWT==2.8.0
PyMySQL==1.1.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.22
twilio==8.10.0
typing_extensions==4.8.0
urllib3==2.0.7
virtualenv==20.24.5
Werkzeug==3.0.0
yarl==1.9.2
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_cors import CORS
from dataclasses import dataclass
from sqlalchemy import text
from urllib.parse import quote

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000"])


db = SQLAlchemy()

mysql =MySQL()

@dataclass
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1
    

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def as_dict(self):
        excluded_fields = ['id']
        return {field.name:getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c if field.name not in excluded_fields}

@dataclass
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def as_dict(self):
        excluded_fields = ['id']
        return {field.name:getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c if field.name not in excluded_fields}



app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:pwd@127.0.0.1/test'

db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_user():
    users = User.query.all()
    return jsonify(users)

@app.route('/user/<firstname>', methods=['GET'])
def user_byfirstname(firstname):
    user = User.query.filter_by(firstname = firstname).first()
    return jsonify(user.as_dict())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

App tree:

[image]

I then go to the Terminal, and run `$ docker build -t myapp:latest` .

The build is successful, and I can see my app listed in the Docker Desktop app

I then run

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py:144: SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as __main__.User, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.
  super().__init__(name, bases, d, **kwargs)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 581-248-767
```

Docker Desktop shows myapp is in use.

So far, so good. But this is where I start running into issues.

From host machine (through Postman) I cannot access the app on port 8080 with:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/users
```

Postman throws the error : `Error: read ECONNRESET`

I really don't know what to do or where to go from here, every source I've tried has given me a slight variation on what I have already attempted, and I'm no closer to getting this to work. Please help, thanks.

Comment: From the Flask output it looks like its only running on localhost and not all interfaces (`--host=0.0.0.0`) as you intended. If you were actually running on 0.0.0.0 it should output `* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)` and then the addresses which are localhost and probably 10.X.X.X

Comment: So I’ve to remove --host=0.0.0.0 to make it work ?

Comment: No, `--host-0.0.0.0` is not working. I don't know how your `app.py` file looks like but clearly the argument is not working as its only running on your containers local network. Check how your `app.py` is reading that argument and how its telling flask to run. Usually flask development apps are ran with `flask --app app_name run --host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: I updated my post with the content of app.py. Do you see something wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the Flask server points out that its only running on the containers local network. (127.0.0.1) and not on all interfaces.

That is because you are running the flask development server with `python3 app.py --host=0.0.0.0`. When you run it like that, Flask run with the default values and with the values given through the function `app.run()`.

The recommended way is to use the flask cli command to run your app so you can configure flask externally and not hard code variables or modify your `app.run()` with the variables you need.

- The recommended way would be to change your dockerfile and use flask cli like this:

  ```
  FROM python:3.11-alpine
  # Virtual envs not needed inside container
  WORKDIR /app
  COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
  COPY . /app
  RUN python3 -m pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

  EXPOSE 5000
  CMD ["flask", "--app=app", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
  ```
- The other option is modifying your `app.run()` and add the host parameter:

  ```py
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
  ```

Comment: It dosn't work. I edited my code like you suggested and I get this error : `python3: can't open file '/app/flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when running the cmd : $ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest. (I updated my post with my file tree)

Comment: Don't run flask with Python just run flask cli directly. Did you remove `ENTRYPOINT` from your dockerfile?

Comment: I removed the `ENTRYPOINT` and it still doesn't work, I have this error : `Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app.app'. Use 'app.app:name' to specify one.`  However the second option with  `app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")`  makes my project work

Answer (score 0):

Use gunicorn or another production grade WSGI server to start flask apps.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/gunicorn/

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/

command should be something like:
/path/to/python/install/or/venv/python -m gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - wsgi:app